# Port Forwarding not working

Tags: port-forwarding, webserver

I have been trying to run the Webserver from my home machine, and have configured the modem accordingly. but still not able to make it work.

I have WAMP installed, and my PC ip is 192.168.1.5, Once I "Put Online" WAMP, I am able to run localhost from "192.168.1.5", So I think Localhost is not attached to my machine IP,

I have opened port 80 on my modem to forward the request to my local ip.

[image: modem screenshot view image in new tab for full length]

My modem model is "ZXDSL 831IIV7"

I tried to run from my WAN Ip on my local machine it always asks me for the modem's username/password, and if I run it from proxy or http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ is says the site is down.

Thanks..

Comment: This could be caused by having your modem's WAN side web interface enabled. Check and make sure that it's turned off for WAN, but enabled for LAN. Some modems come with both WAN and LAN web interfaces enabled. Enabling the WAN side is a bad idea whether or not you're trying to run your own web server.

Comment: "Remote Management" is what you are looking for, there will be an option that allows you to remote manage your router from the internet via a web gui

Comment: @vickash no the wan interface is not open, I have checked it,

Comment: @Paul No I am not look remote management.. I just want if i open my ip from another computer i goes to my localhost where I am running a prject.

Comment: I mean't you need to look for "Remote Management" in your router and make sure it is turned off.  Though I suspect the reason might be your ISP blocks incoming http connections.  Have you checked?

Comment: @Paul Remote Management is Disabled. Can you please tell help, how can i check if My IPS blocked the incoming connections

Comment: The simplest way might be to just ask them.  Say you need to access your router remotely for management, but access seems to be blocked.